# Migrating from SQL Server CE to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, data-migration

Currently I am using SQL Server CE for persisting my data for which I am providing with a `.sdf` and connection string mentioned in `app.config` pointing to this `.sdf` file.

Now I want to provide user with the flexibility to have the data stored in their own SQL Server database if present at there disposal.

Now I am facing the problem of how to change the connection string at runtime if user chooses to uses its own database ?

Or if restrict them to use my predefined `.mdf` file how to attach that in their SQL Server ?

Comment: That'll be tough - since for SQL Server CE, you need to use stuff like `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` while for a "real" SQL Server, those are `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. Just switching the connection string isn't enough ....

Comment: Unless you use DbConnection DbCommand etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to have 2 connection strings in the configuration file (app or web). There is a special section for them intuitively called [ConnectionStrings](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx). You can then switch between them based on other settings.

Answer (score 0):

Changing connection strings dynamically is actually pretty easy to do as long as you have a place to store the new settings (ie. web or app config files). If you provide a way for them to enter the server information you can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to update your app/web.config.

Ado.net typically has parameters on almost any db connection object that allows you to specify the connection string as an arguement. Additionally, there are helper classes that can be used to construct the connection string on the fly like the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) or EntityConnectionStringBuilder. I personally love the Entity Framework as it allows you to create the database from the model itself if it does not already exist, provided you already have the connection string.